# c# console app web browser TaskCompletionSource halting console app

Tags: c#, console-application

Below is my code. checked in debug mode and noticed program execution halts at await `tcs.Task` like.
The same code runs fine winform application and gives fully loaded html page. Trying same in console application.

```
namespace WebBrowserConsole2
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetFeatureBrowserEmulation();

            Program objpro = new Program();
            objpro.CallDynamicPage();

        }

        async public void CallDynamicPage()
        {
            try
            {
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(100000000); // cancel in 10s

                var html = await LoadDynamicPage("mysiteURL", cts.Token);
                MessageBox.Show(html.Substring(0, 1024) + "..."); // it's too long!
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        async Task<string> LoadDynamicPage(string url, CancellationToken token)
        {
            WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(webBrowser);
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = (s, arg) =>
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);

            try
            {
                using (token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: true))
                {
                    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;
                    try
                    {
                        webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                        webBrowser.Navigate(url);
                        await tcs.Task;  // execution stops here. and programs ends here
                    }
                    catch (Exception exTask)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("exTask-> " + exTask.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException exc)
            {
            }


            var documentElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];

            var html = documentElement.OuterHtml;
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(500, token);

                if (webBrowser.IsBusy)
                    continue;

                var htmlNow = documentElement.OuterHtml;
                if (html == htmlNow)
                    break;

                html = htmlNow;
            }

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            return html;
        }

        static void SetFeatureBrowserEmulation()
        {
            if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Runtime)
                return;
            var appName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                appName, 11000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slapping `STAThread` on `Main` doesn't make your thread an STA thread. It does *mark* it as an STA thread, but *making* it an STA thread is up to you.

Specifically, you need to do some form of Win32 message pumping. The easiest way to do this is with a WPF Dispatcher. There are also ways to get it working using Windows Forms types. Or you could write your own message pump.

On a side note, this comment is misleading, since the actual timeout is 27 hours, 46 minutes, and 40 seconds - not "10s":

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(100000000); // cancel in 10s
```